# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination 2131297025 is not a direct child of this NavGraph

Tags: android, graph

I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination 2131297025 is not a direct child of this NavGraph` in Logcat. And app crashed on line `navController.setGraph(graph, Bundle())`.

But I want to know what dest/id this number `2131297025`represented, so I could fix this problem. And not sure why it showed me an integer number instead of the dest name or id.

Comment: If you're just getting a number, then you manually set the `startDestinationId` on your graph. And that ID doesn't correspond with a screen in that graph. Show your graph XML code and what you are doing before your `setGraph` call.

Comment: I solved this problem. The reason could be that I included `<include app:graph="@navigation/bbb" />` layout bbb in aaa's layout xml. And try to `setStartDestination` of 1 fragement of bbb from aaa directly. And it seems Android does not allow it. Pretty new to Android, I might be wrong.